# Store custom enum in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, rust

I'm currently storing the user plan in a mongobd, using this enum:

```
use mongodb::bson::oid::ObjectId;

pub enum Plan {
 Free,
 Pro,
 Other(ObjectId)
}
```

I implemented the std::convert::From for the Bson object using serde_json. It got the right result on 'Free' and 'Pro', but gives 'unknown variant' error for the last one.

I tried looking online but couldn't find any useful resource.

Comment: where is your code for conversion though?